# How to make a junior statement from hire_date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

so I want to make data where the difference of years from hiredate to the current date (wearing sysdate) has a difference of 0 to 2 years then it will be junior, and if 3 to 5 then go to senior

i use code like this

```
 select first_name, trunc(months_between(sysdate,hire_date) /12) as information from employees;
```

desc from employees -
employee_id,first_name,hire_date;

Comment: You need to use [`case`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96) expression

Comment: @astentx can you show me how to use it?

Comment: I've already done. Did you even open the link provided?

Comment: @astentx ohh sorry i didnt see that. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "make data"? You want to "make data" - what does that mean? Then: If between 0 and 2 years then "junior", if between 3 and 5 then "senior". What if it's 2.5 years? Based on your attempt, using TRUNC, I assume if it's strictly less than **3** years then "junior" and if it's strictly less than **6** years then "senior". But what if hire-date was 10 or 15 years ago? Do you want to exclude those from the output, and only show "junior" and "senior"?